# I've dropped iOS 5, how do I remove iOS 5.x from Xcode's scheme target?

Tags: ios, xcode

My app has historically supported iOS 5 & up. We just recently decided to drop support for iOS 5. I removed support from the app by doing the following:

- Clicking on the project's target
- Searching for iOS Deployment Target in Build Settings
- Setting that value to iOS 6.0

However, when I look at the list of possible simulators from the scheme dropdown, I'm still able to choose iOS 5.0 and iOS 5.1.

I'm worried this means I may have not actually set the minimum supported version of my app to 6.0. My app will crash on anything pre-iOS 6, since we've begun to use Auto Layout for some new views. Any new projects only show the latest simulators as scheme targets.

What am I missing? How do I get this dropdown to stop showing me the iOS 5.0 and 5.1 simulator options?

Comment: Xcode's schemes have always been a little too persistent.  Perhaps removing derived data would fix it, but it doesn't do a thing when I've tried it.

Comment: Sometimes quitting and relaunching Xcode gets it to reconsider the scheme situation. And sometimes not.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention: please consider filing a bug report with Apple. You're probably in a situation where you can take a nice screen shot showing clearly that your deployment target is 6.0 but the 5.0 simulator is still appearing in the schemes.

Comment: Bug report filed: Bug ID# 13598550.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing anything.  Setting the Deployment Target will determine the minimum version required for installation of the app.

I don't know of any way to hide an irrelevant target from the scheme dropdown.